# Nginx as reverse proxy for backend. How to specify nginx client certificate

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have nginx as reverse proxy for my back-end. If my back-end is on other host, I want to use client certificate on nginx, then back-end must be configured for checking that certificate. However clients of nginx must not have client certificates, any client (web-browser) can connect to nginx. The question is, how to configure that in nginx config.

My current nginx config:

```
user MyApp;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/CDT.MyApp.WebApp.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    # log_format my_tracking $request_body;
    access_log /var/log/CDT/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/CDT/nginx_error.log;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen *:443 ssl;
        server_name  myapp.somecode.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/somecode.com.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/somecode.com.key;

        gzip on;
        gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
        gzip_comp_level 1;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_types      application/vnd.api+json text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            root   /etc/CDT.MyApp.WebApp_html;
            try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

        location ~ (/api/v3/|/connect/|/\.well-known/) {
            client_max_body_size 0;
            proxy_pass         http://otherhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```